# Python PANDAS: Apply Multi-Line Boolean Criteria Within Group?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with the following general format:

```
id,thing_criteria_field,place_criteria_field
1,thing_1,place_2
1,thing_3,place_2
1,thing_3,place_2
1,thing_7,place_1
2,thing_3,place_3
2,thing_7,place_2
2,thing_9,place_2
2,thing_4,place_5
3,thing_1,place_1
3,thing_2,place_6
3,thing_3,place_6
3,thing_4,place_6
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to apply two boolean criteria within a group that MAY have the criteria values spread across multiple records/lines within a group.  And if these criteria exist, do not filter any records from the group.  If not, filter out all records for a group.

This is a simplified example.  The criteria sets are huge lists which is why I concatenate them with pipes and use str.contains() with regex=True instead of something simpler.

This is what I have come up with so far but I do not think I am even on the right track for handling the possibility of multi-line criteria within groups or returning all when found.

```
thing_criteria = (x.df['thing_criteria_field'].str.contains('thing_1|thing2|thing3', regex=True))
place_criteria = (x.df['place_criteria_field'].str.contains('place_1', regex=True))

df_result = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: (thing_criteria & place_criteria).all())
```

This is the result set I am trying to create from the sample dataset:

```
id,thing_criteria_field,place_criteria_field
1,thing_1,place_2
1,thing_3,place_2
1,thing_3,place_2
1,thing_7,place_1
3,thing_1,place_1
3,thing_2,place_6
3,thing_3,place_6
3,thing_4,place_6
```

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Build a dataframe indicating whether each row meets
# each of the individual criterion
all_criteria = [thing_criteria, place_criteria]
cond = pd.DataFrame(all_criteria).T \
        .assign(id=df['id'])

# Now group them by id and reduce the truth values
#   .any(): test if any row in the group matches a single criterion
#   .all(): test if all criteria are met in the group
match = cond.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:, :-1].any().all())
ids = match[match].index

# Finally, get the ids that matches all criteria
df[df['id'].isin(ids)]
```

---

**How `any().all()` works:** let's say you have the following groups:

```
   thing_criteria_field  place_criteria_field  id
0                  True                 False   1
1                 False                 False   1
2                 False                 False   1
3                 False                  True   1
-------------------------------------------------
any:               True                  True   ==> all: True


   thing_criteria_field  place_criteria_field  id
4                 False                 False   2
5                 False                 False   2
6                 False                 False   2
7                 False                 False   2
-------------------------------------------------
any:              False                 False   ==> all: False
```